# How to hide a div by clicking an anchor button on this selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

---

MY main question is how can i hide only current div which i click ... please suggest me what can i do for that

---

---

```js
$('.ads-close-btn').click(function() {
    $('.full-width-add').hide("slow");
  });

alert('MY main question is how can i hide only current div');
```

```css
.a_text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/16f70ff438.js"></script>
<!--First add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
<!--second add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
<!--third add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
<!--4th add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
```

---

MY main question is how can i hide only current div which i click ... please suggest me what can i do for that

---

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of `this` with jquery `closest()`

```
$('.ads-close-btn').click(function() {
$(this).closest('.full-width-add').hide("slow"); 
});
```

Comment: Only answer with the **correct** `closest()` not `parents()`/`parent()`

Comment: @freedomn-m what is the problem with `.parent()` here...all the div's are different to each other so `.parent()` will work fine here.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal "will work fine *here*" and at *just* this specific instance - yes.  Tomorrow OP decides to add an edit button, and for neatness wants to put it in a box next to the close button, ie with an extra `div` between the current 'parent' and the current 'close' - bang... code stops working, OP has no idea why.   Why? because they used `parent()` which is too rigid and locks the code to your html layout, which there was no reason to do.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line

```
$(this).parents('.full-width-add:first').hide("slow");
```

instead of

```
$('.full-width-add').hide("slow");
```

```js
$('.ads-close-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.full-width-add:first').hide("slow");
});
```

```css
.a_text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/16f70ff438.js"></script>
<!--First add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
<!--second add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
<!--third add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
<!--4th add div-->
<div class='full-width-add'>
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `this` with `parents` function

```
$('.ads-close-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.full-width-add').hide("slow");
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8fv6os7/

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
$('.full-width-add')
```

you are actually selecting ALL elements with .full-width-add class.

Try replacing your function by:

```
$('.ads-close-btn').click(function() {
$(this).parent().hide("slow"); 
});
```

This way you only select the parent of the close button.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the snippet for the same.

```js
$('.ads-close-btn').click(function() {
  var curId=$(this).attr('id');
      $('#div'+curId).hide("slow");
  });

alert('MY main question is how can i hide only current div');
```

```css
.a_text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/16f70ff438.js"></script>
<!--First add div-->
<div class='full-width-add' id="div1">
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn' id="1"><i class='fa fa-close' ></i></a>
</div>
<!--second add div-->
<div class='full-width-add' id="div2">
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn' id="2"><i class='fa fa-close' i></i></a>
</div>
<!--third add div-->
<div class='full-width-add' id="div3">
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn' id="3"><i class='fa fa-close' ></i></a>
</div>
<!--4th add div-->
<div class='full-width-add' id="div4" >
  <div class='a_text'>some text</div>
  <a href='#' class='ads-close-btn' id="4"><i class='fa fa-close' ></i></a>
</div>
```